# How to get floating window in mac os x

Tags: cocoa

Sorry, i don't know what that window is called. Its more like a dialog box I think. Mac app cheatsheet ( http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/ ) or keycue ( http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/ ) have it. How to build an app with that kind of window?

Answer (score 2):

You want to make an NSPanel and set its window level. Experiment with the available window levels defined in CGWindowLevel.h and see which one is most appropriate for your app.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Apple's sample code for RoundTransparentWindow:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Also, there's an old tutorial here:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html